# Transforming a cis double-bond to a trans double-bond using any mechanisms of my choice

Tags: organic-chemistry

For my final, I need to be able to a trans-double bond from a cis double bond. Here is what I drew:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I essentially created a triple bond and oxidized

Comment: Yes that is fine. But converting a triple bond to a double bond is reduction, not oxidation.

Comment: Heating it also would work, but that's probably not what the boring syllabuses want from you. :)

Comment: Adding HBr and subsequent elimination should also produce a trans double bond as the main product.

Comment: I like the bromination step.  Since you have geminal halogens you can use magnesium shavings to elimnate them to re-form your alkene which should give you a trans maolecule.